# How to use & differently than normal inside an `align` environment?

Tags: align, xstring, catcodes

I'm trying to write a macro to let me write logic formulae in a more natural syntax. I've come up with a working version which however has a problem when used inside `align` environments (and in `tabular` as well).

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \Box
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\logic{m}{%
  \def\@formula{#1}%
  \saveexpandmode
  \expandarg
  \foreach \keyword/\operator in \@operators {%
    \StrSubstitute{\@formula}{\keyword}{\operator}[\@temp]%
    \global\let\@formula\@temp
  }%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \@formula
}

% Here the list of recognised syntax with the corresponding commands
\def\@operators{
  []/\Box,
  <>/\Diamond,
  !/\neg,
  &&/\land,
  ||/\lor,
  <->/\leftrightarrow,
  ->/\rightarrow,
  <-/\leftarrow
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a valid modal logic formula: $\logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}$

This is a display modal logic formula:
\begin{align}
 \logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If I comment the second paragraph, the output is the following:

[image: output]

However, the same macro used inside the `align` environment gets totally mad, producing hundreds of error messages.

I was expecting problems when using `&` which is an active character with special meaning in `align`. I suppose the problem is that `align` splits beforehand the content of the line into two parts, `\logic{[]p -> p` and `<>[]p}`, which then cause all the troubles. Is that right?

Indeed, if I avoid using `&` in the formula and *comment out the `&&/\land` line* in the `@operators` macro, the macro works inside `align` as well.

Note that everything works in `equation`, using `&` as well.

Is there a way to make this code work inside `align`? Or is there a way to achieve the same result that works inside `align`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I enclosed the `\logic` definition in an extra set of braces.

Depending on your need for letting information get into or out of the boundaries of `\logic`, an alternative "brace hack" may be used in lieu of the extra braces.  See [Understanding Brace Hacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418621/understanding-brace-hacks).  For example, `\DeclareDocumentCommand\logic{m}{\iffalse{\fi...\iffalse}\fi}` also works, plus gives the ability for the formula to be surrounded by math with binary/unary information being transmittable across the boundary. See more in **SUPPLEMENT**.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for `align`
\usepackage{latexsym}% for \Box
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\logic{m}{{%
  \gdef\@formula{#1}%
  \saveexpandmode
  \expandarg
  \foreach \keyword/\operator in \@operators {%
    \StrSubstitute{\@formula}{\keyword}{\operator}[\@temp]%
    \global\let\@formula\@temp
  }%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \@formula
}}

% Here the list of recognised syntax with the corresponding commands
\def\@operators{
  []/\Box,
  <>/\Diamond,
  !/\neg,
  &&/\land,
  ||/\lor,
  <->/\longleftrightarrow,
  ->/\longrightarrow,
  <-/\longleftarrow
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a valid modal logic formula: $\logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}$

This is a display modal logic formula:
\begin{align}
 \logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT: BRACE HACKS**

Here is an example of how the brace hack makes a difference.  Compare the two cases, the first with extra braces, the 2nd with a brace hack.  In the 2nd case, the binary nature of the `+` communicates with the prior `y` to provide proper spacing around the `+`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for `align`
\usepackage{latexsym}% for \Box
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\logic{m}{{%
  \gdef\@formula{#1}%
  \saveexpandmode
  \expandarg
  \foreach \keyword/\operator in \@operators {%
    \StrSubstitute{\@formula}{\keyword}{\operator}[\@temp]%
    \global\let\@formula\@temp
  }%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \@formula
}}

% Here the list of recognised syntax with the corresponding commands
\def\@operators{
  []/\Box,
  <>/\Diamond,
  !/\neg,
  &&/\land,
  ||/\lor,
  <->/\longleftrightarrow,
  ->/\longrightarrow,
  <-/\longleftarrow
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a valid modal logic formula: $\logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}$

This is a display modal logic formula:
\begin{align}
 y \logic{+ []p -> p && <>[]p}
\end{align}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\logic{m}{\iffalse{\fi%
  \gdef\@formula{#1}%
  \saveexpandmode
  \expandarg
  \foreach \keyword/\operator in \@operators {%
    \StrSubstitute{\@formula}{\keyword}{\operator}[\@temp]%
    \global\let\@formula\@temp
  }%
  \restoreexpandmode
  \@formula
\iffalse}\fi}

\begin{align}
 y\logic{+ []p -> p && <>[]p}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't expecting an answer so easy and perfectly working! Thanks

Comment: Since you use `\global\let\@formula\@temp`, you should also do `\gdef\@formula{#1}`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  Is that so there is no confusion over whether a local or a global variable is being employed at any given moment?

Comment: It's not simply a question of confusion: with local and global assignments to the same variable, you can exhaust memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the full power of `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \Box
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\logic{m}
 {
  \group_align_safe_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_gigabytes_logic_input_tl { #1 }
  \clist_map_function:NN \c_gigabytes_logic_subs_clist \gigabytes_logic_sub:n
  \tl_use:N \l_gigabytes_logic_input_tl
  \group_align_safe_end:
 }
\tl_new:N \l_gigabytes_logic_input_tl
\clist_const:Nn \c_gigabytes_logic_subs_clist
 {
  []/\Box,
  <>/\Diamond,
  !/\neg,
  &&/\land,
  ||/\lor,
  <->/\longleftrightarrow,
  ->/\rightarrow,
  <-/\leftarrow
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gigabytes_logic_sub:n
 {
  \__gigabytes_logic_sub:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gigabytes_logic_sub:w #1 / #2 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_gigabytes_logic_input_tl { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here is a valid modal logic formula: $\logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}$

This is a display modal logic formula:
\begin{align}
\logic{[]p -> p && <>[]p}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Points to note:

1. The `&` tokens are hidden from `align` by using `\group_align_safe_begin:` and `\group_align_safe_end:`
2. The routine for substitution is easier and needs no juggling with expansion modes

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Why is DeclareDocumentCommand not suggested “routinely”?

Comment: @gigabytes Because it silently redefines existing commands.

Comment: Ah you meant in contrast to \New.. and \Renew versions, not in contrast to \newcommand & co.  Yes I agree, I copied the snippet from some package cose where it made sense

Comment: I've edited the question to follow your advices that were not directly related to the issue at hand. If you want you may edit the answer as well.