# Help to make a faster token replacing macro

Tags: programming, strings, xstring

I have a macro called `\logic` which helps me write logical formulas faster by simplifying some common logical symbols. So when I write `$\logic{p -> q}$` I obtain `$p \to q$`.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%
% Command to format a formula with a succinct and natural syntax
%
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}% for \StrSubstitute
\usepackage{pgffor}% for \foreach

% the strange `\iffalse{\fi` thing is a 'brace hack', to make this work inside
% `tabular`-like envs. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452442
\NewDocumentCommand\logic{+m}{\iffalse{\fi
  \def\gt@formula{#1}%
  \saveexpandmode
  \saveexploremode
  \expandarg
  \exploregroups
  \foreach \gt@keyword/\gt@operator in \gt@logic@operators {%
    \StrSubstitute{\gt@formula}{\gt@keyword}{\gt@operator}[\@temp]%
    \global\let\gt@formula\@temp
  }%
  \restoreexploremode
  \restoreexpandmode
  \ensuremath{\gt@formula}%
\iffalse}\fi}

\def\gt@logic@operators{}

\NewDocumentCommand\RegisterLogicOperators{m}{
  \def\gt@logic@operators{#1}
}

\makeatother

\RegisterLogicOperators{
  !/\neg,
  &&/\land,
  &/\land,
  \&/\land,
  ||/\lor,
  |/\lor,
  <->/\longleftrigtharrow,
  ->/\to,
  ~>/\leadsto,
  <-/\impliedby,
  <</\llangle,
  >>/\rrangle,
  <=/\le,
  >=/\ge,
  ==/\equiv,
  [[/\llbracket,
  ]]/\rrbracket,
}


\begin{document}

This is a logic formula: $\logic{((p -> q) & p) -> q}$.


\end{document}
```

However, the macro is very slow. You don't notice when you use it once, but in a paper with heavy usage the compilation time goes up very quickly. I suppose the bottleneck here is the `\StrSubstitute` macro from the `xstring` package, which seems a bit overkill for what I have to do, but I do not know how to obtain the same result faster. Also note that the real-world usage has a much longer list of replacements in the call to `\RegisterLogicOperators`.

Is there a way to improve the performance of this macro?

Comment: Maybe LuaLaTeX callback string substitution would be faster? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500372/conditional-string-replacements-in-lualatex for an example.

Comment: I cannot depend on LuaLaTeX unfortunately :(

Comment: Another thought: Do you have a lot of repeated usages of arguments to `\logic`? It would be fairly simple to memoize the results from `\logic` in that case.

Comment: Nope, formulas are always different unfortunately

Comment: Mention of brace hacks...another link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418621/understanding-brace-hacks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this solution in LaTeX3, which converts the entire string in one go. I tried to convert 1000 expressions at once, and it takes less than 5 seconds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_symbol_conv_prop
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_symbol_conv_prop {
  !=\neg,
  &&=\land,
  &=\land,
  \&=\land,
  ||=\lor,
  |=\lor,
  <->=\longleftrightarrow,
  ->=\to,
  ~>=\leadsto,
  <-=\impliedby,
  <<=\llangle,
  >>=\rrangle,
  {<=}=\le,
  {>=}=\ge,
  {==}=\equiv,
  [[=\llbracket,
  ]]=\rrbracket
}

% convert keys to string
\prop_new:N \g_str_symbol_conv_prop
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_symbol_conv_prop {
  \prop_put:Nxx \g_str_symbol_conv_prop {\tl_to_str:n {#1}} {\exp_not:n {#2}}
}

\cs_set:Npn \mult_level_lookup_name:n #1 {
  __g_symbol_lookup_\int_to_alph:n{#1}_seq
}

% find longest symbol
\int_new:N \g_longest_symbol_len_int
\int_set:Nn \g_longest_symbol_len_int {0}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_str_symbol_conv_prop {
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\str_count:n {#1}}
  \int_set:Nn \g_longest_symbol_len_int {
    \int_max:nn {\g_longest_symbol_len_int} {\l_tmpa_int}
  }
}

% create multi-level look up tables
\int_step_inline:nn {\g_longest_symbol_len_int} {
  \seq_new:c {\mult_level_lookup_name:n {#1}}
}

% fill multi-level lookup tables
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g_str_symbol_conv_prop {
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
  \int_step_inline:nn {\str_count:N \l_tmpa_str} {
    \seq_push:cx {\mult_level_lookup_name:n {##1}} {
      \str_item:Nn \l_tmpa_str {##1}
    }
  }
}

\tl_new:N \l_logic_result_tl
\int_new:N \l_current_level_int
\str_new:N \l_current_logic_str
\str_new:N \l_current_symbol_str

\msg_new:nnn {logic} {invalidsymbol} {"#1" is not a valid symbol}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_rescan:nn {nV}


\cs_set:Npn \logic_conv:n #1 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_current_logic_str {#1}
  \int_set:Nn \l_current_level_int {1}
  \tl_clear:N \l_logic_result_tl
  \str_clear:N \l_current_symbol_str
  
  \bool_do_until:nn {\str_if_empty_p:N \l_current_logic_str} {
    % pop first item
    \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {\str_head:N \l_current_logic_str}
    \str_set:Nx \l_current_logic_str {\str_tail:N \l_current_logic_str}
    
    % check if this item can be found in the look up table
    \seq_if_in:cVTF {\mult_level_lookup_name:n {\l_current_level_int}} \l_tmpa_str {
      % if it can be found, advance level and store it into \l_current_symbol_str
      \int_incr:N \l_current_level_int
      \str_put_right:NV \l_current_symbol_str \l_tmpa_str
    }
    {
      % if it cannot be found, it could be the end of a symbol
      % or just a normal string
      \str_if_empty:NF \l_current_symbol_str {
        % if \l_current_symbol_str is not empty, it is the end of a symbol
        % we need to insert the correct symbol and reset variables
        \prop_get:NVNTF \g_str_symbol_conv_prop \l_current_symbol_str \l_tmpa_tl {
          \int_set:Nn \l_current_level_int {1}
          \str_clear:N \l_current_symbol_str
          \tl_put_right:NV \l_logic_result_tl \l_tmpa_tl
        } {
          \tl_put_right:NV \l_logic_result_tl \l_current_symbol_str
          \int_set:Nn \l_current_level_int {1}
          \str_clear:N \l_current_symbol_str
        }
      }
      \tl_put_right:NV \l_logic_result_tl \l_tmpa_str
    }
  }
  % output last item
  \prop_get:NVNTF \g_str_symbol_conv_prop \l_current_symbol_str \l_tmpa_tl {
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_logic_result_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  } { \tl_put_right:NV \l_logic_result_tl \l_current_symbol_str }
  
  %\tl_show:N \l_logic_result_tl
  \tl_rescan:nV {} \l_logic_result_tl
}

\newcommand{\logic}[1]{
  \logic_conv:n {#1}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\logic{((p -> q) & p | !r) <= >= == -> <- c | d \phi || \sigma}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I try to compile your code I get some `undefined control sequence` errors, such as:
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\__prop_pair:wn #1\s__prop #2->\prop_put:Nxx `
`\g_str_symbol_conv_prop {\tl_to...`
`l.32 }`

Comment: @gigabytes Probably the `Nxx` variant is only added in latest `expl3`. I have modified the code.

Comment: Thanks, now TeX stops on this:
`\l_logic_result_tl=((p \to  q) \land  p \lor  \neg r) \le  \ge  \equiv  \to `
`\impliedby  c \lor  d.`
`<recently read> }`
                 
`l.125 ...((p -> q) & p | !r) <= >= == -> <- c | d}`
`                                                  $`

Comment: This is just showing what the content of `\l_logic_result_tl` is for debug purposes. You can simply skip it or comment out `\tl_show:N \l_logic_result_tl `.

Comment: Ok, now it compiles fine! However, it does something different. If I say for example `\logic{\phi -> \psi}` I get the `->` translated correctly, but `\phi` and `\psi` appear as "\phi" and "\psi" on the typeset output! In my version, everything that is not in the list of translated tokens is left as is. Here it seems as if it was passed to `\string`. Can it be fixed somehow? Unfortunately, `expl3` is completely opaque to me

Comment: @gigabytes You should have mentioned it earlier. The design needs to be changed, which can take some time.

Comment: @gigabytes Having `\&` and `&` pointing to the same thing seems redundant. If `\&` can be removed, it would be much easier to write a solution.

Comment: I’m very sorry, I thought it was clear from the original code. Yes, we can remove \& without problems

Comment: @gigabytes No problem at all! I just realized that this problem can be patched with one command. Please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you! I get again some undefined control sequence errors. Maybe I should just update (but I need it to work on Overleaf, so...):
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\__prop_pair:wn #1\s__prop #2->\prop_put:Nxx `
`\g_str_symbol_conv_prop {\tl_to...`

Comment: Ah I just had to backport the first fix and now it works. And it's way faster indeed! Thank you!

Comment: @gigabytes Can you estimate how much faster it is? I am really interested in knowing  Judging by your previous version, I would say the speed-up is roughly proportionate to the number of symbols defined.

Comment: Well, I have a 50 pages article with heavy use of the macro that timed out on Overleaf and took nearly a minute to compile locally, now compiles in under 5 seconds!